# Mysql query based on date?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this

```
id | date | content
1  | 09-16-2013 | content 1 here
2  | 09-23-2013 | content 2 here 
3  | 09-30-2013 | content 3 here
```

I would like to display the content for a week from that date. For example, the first content should start on 9/16/2013 and then show until 9/22/2013 mid night. then on next day, it changes to the content 2.
Same way,when I am on content 2, I want to display like "previous week content" and then show just the previous ones..I think I can do this by checking the current date and then anything below that has to be displayed.

I am not very good at these kind of mysql queries, please advise!

Regards

Comment: A week from what date, current date?

Comment: Use the `WEEK()` function in MySQL.

Comment: yes if the table has today's date then for a weeek from that date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like this

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM table1
 WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL 0 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY
                AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 6 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY
```

This query will grab a row(s) where `date` column is within the boundaries of the current calendar week (from Monday to Sunday).

[`WEEKDAY()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) function  *returns the weekday index for date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 = Sunday)*. The expression

```
CURDATE() + INTERVAL 0 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY
```

returns a date for Monday of the current calendar week and

```
CURDATE() + INTERVAL 6 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY
```

returns a date for Sunday of the current calendar week.
Using `BETWEEN` in `WHERE` clause makes sure that a query returns only rows with `date` values that falls between these two dates (Monday through Sunday).

**Note:** Make sure that you have an index on `date` column. This query is index-friendly.

Sample output for today's date (09/19/2013):

```
+------+------------+----------------+
| id   | date       | content        |
+------+------------+----------------+
|    1 | 2013-09-16 | content 1 here |
+------+------------+----------------+
```

**UPDATE:** To get records for previous calendar week you just substract 1 week interval from both values in `BETWEEN`

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM table1
 WHERE date 
   BETWEEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL 0 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY - INTERVAL 1 WEEK,
       AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 6 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

Comment: I think this is what I need! Will check and get back here to vote up!

Comment: can you please add little explanation of how this query works ..?

Comment: thank you @peterm ! I will check it with several records and test it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jay You're very welcome :) See updated answer for some explanation.

Comment: Thank you! it helps. One last question. For my question where I want to show the previous week's content, should I just manipulate the BETWEEN condition? For example, next week Monday, I should show this week's content . same way , 3 weeks from now I should show past two weeks under "previous week" section along with that current week's content.

Comment: @Jay Yes, it's correct. Just adjust values in `BETWEEN` for appropriate number of weeks. See updated answer for an example.

Comment: thanks a lot! You saved so much time. I now understand that there are so many things in mysql that I should know!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '09-16-2013' AND '09-22-2013';
```

Comment: I cannot have the date in the query..this is like quote of the week so have all records in the mysql table for each week ...so for example, every monday i will have a new quote so from that date until 1 week need to show the same content.

Answer (score 0):

keyword is [WEEK()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

```
SELECT id,date, CONCAT('content ',WEEK(date),' to here') as content  FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN '9/16/2013 00:00:00.00' AND '9/22/2013 00:00:00.00'
```

Answer (score 0):

To select it dynamically, try something like

```
SELECT * FROM `yourTable` WHERE NOW() >= STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m-%d-%Y') ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m-%d-%Y') DESC LIMIT 1
```

or t

```
SELECT * FROM `yourTable` WHERE CURDATE() >= STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m-%d-%Y') ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m-%d-%Y') DESC LIMIT 1
```

sqlfiddle example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62982/4

Comment: Also, if you remove the `LIMIT 1` from these queries, it will return all the previous 'contents' in the same query - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62982/5. You could also change it to `LIMIT 2` to get just the current and previous week - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62982/6

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the week offset to your needs

```
SET @weekOffset = +2;
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE WEEK(`date`) = WEEK(NOW()) + @weekOffset;
```

See a working demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a7b8/5)